# AWS SNS sms not receving in canada

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am sending AWS SNS via javascript SDK.

```
    let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1',accessKeyId: key,
    secretAccessKey:secret, });

 const params = {
            Message: 'test message here'
            PhoneNumber:'+1<numberhere>'
        };

     let publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({ apiVersion: '2010-03-31' }).publish(params).promise();
        publishTextPromise.then(function (data){
            console.log('message',data);

        }).catch(function (error){
            console.log('error',error);
        })
```

The problem is the Canadian numbers not receiving the SMS but Indian numbers are working fine.
Does anyone have any workaround for this??.

Comment: Did you try sending a test message from the Amazon SNS console? If it has the same result as via the API call, then it's not a coding issue. If possible, try sending to a different Canadian number to confirm that it is not related to the number itself.

Comment: have you enabled cloudwatch and see what the error logs say , is the sms type promotional and the number you are trying to send to is DND ?

Comment: How can enable cloud watch for this??